# Parametric3DPlot Problem

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

It is given the following problem:
$$X'=Z+(Y-\alpha)X$$
$$Y'=1-\beta Y-X^2$$
$$Z'=-X-\gamma Z$$
with initial conditions $(X(0),Y(0),Z(0)=(1,2,3)$.

Where

X: interest rate

Υ:investment demand

Z: price index

$\alpha$: savings,
$\beta$: cost per investment,
$\gamma$: the absolute value of the elasticity of demand

***UPDATED***

I am trying to solve this problem with the NDSolve command

```
\[Alpha] = 0.9;
\[Beta] = 0.2;
\[Gamma] = 1.2;
deq1 = x'[t] == z[t] + (y[t] - \[Alpha])*x[t]
deq2 = y'[t] == 1 - \[Beta]*y[t] - x[t]^2
deq3 = z'[t] == -x[t] - \[Gamma]*z[t]
soln = NDSolve[{deq1, deq2, deq3, x[0] == 1, y[0] == 3, 
   z[0] == 2}, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 1000}]
soln1 = NDSolveValue[{deq1, deq2, deq3, x[0] == 1, y[0] == 3, 
      z[0] == 2}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 1000}]
ParametricPlot3D[{soln[[1]][t], soln[[2]][t], soln[[3]][t]}, {t, 0, 
   1000}, AxesLabel -> {"x(t)", "y(t)", "z(t)"}, BaseStyle -> 14, 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: 1. You've defined `soln1`, why not use it? 2. Please don't ask distinctly different questions in one post. 3. You're making the same mistake as in your [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/278969/1871). 4. Implementing Euler method for 3 equations is essentially the same as for 2 equations, please read the answer you've obtained carefully and make some effort to understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- should be `y'[t] == 1 - β*y[t] - x[t]^2;`

```
Clear["Global`*"];
α = 0.9;
β = 0.2;
γ = 1.2;
deq1 = x'[t] == z[t] + (y[t] - α)*x[t];
deq2 = y'[t] == 1 - β*y[t] - x[t]^2;
deq3 = z'[t] == -x[t] - γ*z[t];
soln = NDSolve[{deq1, deq2, deq3, x[0] == 1, y[0] == 3, 
    z[0] == 2}, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 1000}];
ParametricPlot3D[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. soln, {t, 0, 1000}, 
 PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 8]
```

- If we using `NDSolveValue`,then `Through@soln1@t` work.

```
soln1 = NDSolveValue[{deq1, deq2, deq3, x[0] == 1, y[0] == 3, 
   z[0] == 2}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 1000}]
ParametricPlot3D[Through@soln1@t, {t, 0, 1000}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x(t)", "y(t)", "z(t)"}, BaseStyle -> 14, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 8]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, the second function is $Y'=1-\beta Y-X^2$ as you mentioned

Comment: Thank you so much!! I updated my post. Any suggestions for Improved Euler Method?

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos   We can post a new question about the Euler Method since it is hard to the original question.